# How to get a list of all models and their attributes from a C# project?

Tags: c#, excel, oracle, mongodb, visual-studio

**The Short Version:**

I need an excel spreadsheet with all the models & properties from a C# project like this:

```
 ______________________________________________________________________________
| Model | Property | Collection | Ignore | ReadOnly | Required | Default Value |
|=======|==========|============|========|==========|==========|===============|
| Car   | WheelCt  |            |        |          | y        | 4             |
|-------+----------+------------+--------+----------+----------+---------------|
| Car   | PwrWin   | y          |        |          |          |               |
|-------+----------+------------+--------+----------+----------+---------------|
| Car   | uid      |            | y      |          | y        |               |
|-------+----------+------------+--------+----------+----------+---------------|
| Car   | VIN      |            |        | y        | y        |               |
|=======|==========|============|========|==========|==========|===============|
```

Visual Studio seems to be able to go through the code, and pick out the models, is there any way to harness this to output a csv or xls file?

---

**The Long Version:**

My end goal is to convert the back end of this C# project from Oracle to Mongo, so if you know a shortcut, feel free to interject.

We have an in-house tool that will read an excel spreadsheet and build an interface to Mongo based on it.

I have been tasked with making that spreadsheet.

My original thought - because it's what I'm most comfortable with - was to use angular, jquery, and python to change each .cs file to a .txt file, then run basically a text mining script to find the model and attribute names.

But it seems like Visual Studio has a way to pick out the models from the solution. Is there any way to harness this to build this spreadsheet?